# How to create a timer event which will start another timer to store the time passed since in a variable when raised?

Tags: c#, events, timer, event-handling

I have classes `Machine` and `Production`. `Machine` class has a property called `IsProducing` which indicates whether there is a production running in the machine. `Production` class `EstimatedTime` to calculate the remaining time of the production and `TimePassedSince` to calculate the time passed since the completion of the production.

After all the checking returns true, I start the production, change `IsProducing = 1;`, and calculate the estimated time which I pass as an interval to the timer I create.

I want to have an event which will be raised when the timer ticks, after which the `IsProducing = 0;`, the current time is registered as `EndTime` and a new timer is started to calculate the `TimePassedSince`.

I have the following code on Production.cs:

```
 public delegate void EstimatedTimePassedHandler(Production production, Machine machine);
 public event EstimatedTimePassedHandler ProductionStarted;
 public event EstimatedTimePassedHandler ProductionCompleted;
```

I have the following code on Form.cs:

```
if (dh.StartProduction(serialNr, empName) != -1)
                            {
                                machine.IsProducing = 1;
                                Double secondsToGo = machine.CycleTime * production.NrOfLamallae;
                                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToGo);
                                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
                                production.EstimatedTime = dateTime;
                                string displayTime = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
                                tbResult.Text = $"The production is started and will be ready in {displayTime}.";
                                int milliseconds = (int)secondsToGo * 100;
                                Timer timer1 = new Timer { Interval = milliseconds };
                                timer1.Enabled = true;
                                timer1.Tick += new Production.EstimatedTimePassedHandler(this.EstimatedTimerTicked);
                            }
private void EstimatedTimerTicked(Production p, Machine m)
        {
            m.IsProducing = 0; //completed production, not producing anymore
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();    
            /* here I assign the production.EndTime and production.TimePassedSince */
        }
```

It is giving me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'GUI_Designs.Production.EstimatedTimePassedHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

How can I solve this problem? And what is the best practice to handle such an event with a timer tick? And how to store the time passed since inside a variable? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Ok, if it is only about the Handler: You are using a wrong signature for the handler delegate. It shoud be: `void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);`, so in this case `void EstimatedTimerTicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)` which wouldn't be of much use to you.

Comment: But I am wondering: What if your estimation is incorrect or imprecise? Reality and Software would divert pretty fast. Soon, working machines would be shown as "done" and vice versa ...

Comment: @Fildor I used this signature, but changed it to the current one because I need to be able to manipulate machine IsProducing, and production EndTime as well as starting the second timer to store the time passed since. How is it possible with this signature?

Comment: It isn't. With `System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Tick` Event, that is what you get: sender and EventArgs.